# Windows Phone 7: Media file plays multiple times before one finishes

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

My silverlight code:

```
var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("Giggle.wav");
var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
effect.Play();
```

The file, `Giggle.wav` plays multiple times. I expected the code would `wait` while the "Play" method executes.

Suggestions to make it play one instance at a time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [DynamicSoundEffectInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.dynamicsoundeffectinstance.play.aspx)? Play your sound and when BufferNeeded event occurs  - play next one. I am not sure but I think I saw another way how to play a sound synchronously. When I will find I will let you know.

Comment: great, thanks for the response. I will check it out tomorrow.